# Jquery Grid with auto next

Tags: jqgrid

i need code for the jquery grid which should go to next page after few seconds and after it reaches the last page it should call the webservice again to get latest data

Answer (score 0):

What grid are you referring to? If this is a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) then you might use the [jQuery Timers plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers) with the following:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).oneTime(DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS, function() {
        $("#myCustomNextButton").click();
    });
}
```

Refer to [the jqGrid Custom Buttons](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) documentation on how to create your own custom buttons